# Beginner Nested Loops Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

Beginner here in an intro to programming class at Uni learning Python.  I understood most of it until loops and now I am very confused.

Can someone explain why this creates the pattern that it outputs?

```
for i in range(1, 7):
    for j in range(6, 0, -1):
        print(j if j <= i else " ", end = " ")
    print()
```

outer loop triggers and (`i = 1`)

then inner loop triggers and (`j = 6`)

then it doesn't print `j` (6) because `6 <= 1` is `False` and prints 2 blank spaces.

Then at this point does the inner loop end and then goes back to the outer loop for the next iteration?

or does the inner loop continue until 6-1 hits 1?

and if the inner loop continues, does `i` stay 1 the entire inner loop or does it also go up per each inner loop iteration?

i really hope this makes sense.  thank you!

Comment: There are many program visualization tools which can be helpful when learning. [python tutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=for%20i%20in%20range%281,%207%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20j%20in%20range%286,%200,%20-1%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print%28j%20if%20j%20%3C%3D%20i%20else%20%22%20%22,%20end%3D%22%20%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20print%28%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) for example.

Comment: It might be easier to understand something a bit simpler, like `for i in range(5): for j in range(5): print(i, j)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner loop continues until it is exhausted, counting down with `j` going from 6, to 5, to 4 and so on until on the last iteration `j` is 0. While it does so the outer loop doesn't progress: `i` remains 1. Only once the inner loop finishes does the outer loop get a chance to repeat. So then `i` advances to `2` and the inner loop starts all over from 6 again.

Answer (score 1):

First outer loop: i = 1
inner loop iterates: j = 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
And is False, False, False, False, False, True
So produces "     1"

Second outer loop: i = 2
inner loop iterates: j = 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
And is False, False, False, False, True, True
So produces "     2 1"

Third outer loop: i = 3
inner loop iterates: j = 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
And is False, False, False, True, True, True
So produces "     3 2 1"

etc